# Building libraries that have ExternalProjects Added using CMake and Xcode

Tags: xcode, cmake

I am trying to use CMake to build a library (which in turn links to other libraries built via CMake). I am having a couple of issues with this process and would love to have some guidance.

For the library, I have a CMakeLists.txt which essentially has

```
set(SRC srcfile1.cpp srcfile2.cpp)
set(HEADERS srcfile1.h srcfile2.h)

add_library(myLib ${SRC} ${HEADERS})
INSTALL(FILES ${HEADERS} DESTINATION “include/myLib”)
```

For a “Unix Makefiles” generator, with cmake command

```
cmake -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=. -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=debug -G “Unix Makefiles” ..
```

I get an appropriate debug library libMyLib.a in build/src. For a release build type, a release build of libMyLib.a is placed in build/src

However, for an Xcode generator, the library is placed in src/Debug. The issues I am facing here are

a. Doing an Archive in Xcode doesn’t seem to have any effect. I don’t see a corresponding Release library being created anywhere

b. I also have a myLibTests target (which uses googles gtest) which is defined in it’s CMakeLists.txt as

```
  set(SRC myTest.cpp)
  add_executable(myLibTests ${SRC})
  add_dependencies(myLibTests myLib gtest)
  set(gTestLib External/src/gTestLib)
  target_link_libraries(myLibTests myLib gTestLib)
```

When the cmake generator is “Unix Makefiles” myLibTests build, links and runs fine. gTestLib is placed in External/src/gtest-build/. But, when it is “Xcode”, it can’t find the gTest libraries. because, the library is placed in External/src/gTestLib/Debug(or Release) as the case may be (and the above path set in CMakeLists.txt is no longer valid). I am not sure how to set it’s path appropriately in the above set statement.

Since, debug/release is controlled in Xcode (and the configure process in CMake is unaware of this), I assume there isn’t a way to separate the release/debug builds of the gTestLib and also have CMake configure Xcode to pick up the appropriate version while building myLib i.e if I do a debug build of myLib it also does a debug build of gTest and links to it (similar for release builds)? Alternatively, is it possible to configure Xcode to place both the Debug and Release builds in the same location (and then hardcode it’s path above)? What would be the best way of configuring this?

Thanks

Comment: 1. You can add the whole gtest project into your code and just do `add_subdirectory("3rdParty/GTest")` in this case you can use `gtest` as a "local" library. I.e. like your own target: `target_link_libraries(myLibTests myLib gtest)`. 2. Install gtest (Release/Debug or both) first and use `find_package(GTest)` command to locate libs.

Comment: Thanks Ruslo. I went with a different approach. I maintain different folders now for debug/release. In CMakeLists.txt I have a check to see if the generator is XCode and the build type is release. If so, I then set CMAKE_CONFIGURATION_TYPES to Release. This makes the CMake generated XCode project default to Release for all it's builds. Since, I know that it is doing a Release/Debug build during CMake now, I can set the paths to the libraries correctly